# Your Ruby version is X.X.X, but your Gemfile specified X.X.X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

For some reason I'm getting this error when trying to run a ruby script within my bundle.  I've gone through numerous other SO questions and answers, but none of them have solved my problem yet.

I'm doing some testing to make sure the script can run, which may be my problem, so here is my file structure:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── bin
│   └── scan
├── lib
│   ├── functions.rb
│   └── checkin.rb
├── lists
│   ├── default-passwords.txt
│   ├── passwords.txt
│   └── users.txt
├── scan.rb
├── scripts
│   └── check_repo.sh
├── tmp
│   └── export_tracker.yml
└── updates
    └── install.sh
```

I'm testing `checkin.rb`, so in the root of my directory, I'm running `ruby lib/checkin.rb`

The error I'm getting back is:

```
/Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:402:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:88:in `setup'
    from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I've run the following commands and included their output:

`ruby -v` = `ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin15.0]`

`rbenv version` = `2.1.4 (set by /Users/godzilla/Documents/Coding/app/.ruby-version)`

`rbenv local` = `2.1.4`

`rbenv global` = `2.1.4`

Someone also suggested to do the following, but that didn't help:

`gem update bundler`

`bundle install`

`rbenv rehash`

Comment: What is output of `which bundle`? It looks like your bundler is executed by system ruby, not rbenv one

Comment: @Vasfed Here is the output: `/Users/godzilla/.rbenv/shims/bundle`

Comment: What's the output of `rbenv versions`?

Comment: @jeffdill2 `system
* 2.1.4 (set by /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/version)
  2.2.3
  2.3.0
  2.3.0-dev`

Comment: Are you calling `bundle exec ruby lib/checkin.rb` or just `ruby checkin.rb`? It looks like there should be some more info in the backtrace of the error, is that all there is?

Comment: Which line of code in your file is causing the error?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I tried dropping into `sudo -i` and running the command and it worked without a problem... under normal circumstances, this is actually ok, since the script actually needs to run in the context of root.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into some things related to this in the past. Although with a different scope.

This is what I would recommend. It may help, (it helped me), but I would try going to your gemfile and just changing your ruby version from 2.1.4 to 2.0.0.

That is all I did the few times i've had that issue, and it enabled me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which line in your file is causing the issue, but I've solved this problem in the past by using `Bundler.clean_system`. For example:

```
Bundler.clean_system "heroku pg:psql DATABASE -c 'DELETE FROM <table name>' -a <heroku app name>"
```